# Java Inheritance and generics, how to declare a function that applies to "multiple types" of inheritance?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I couldn't find a good question/title for what I want to do. I'm not very familiar with generics, so I have some issues understanding how they work.

Say I have a `Map<k,v>` class that maps keys to values.

```
class Map<K,V>{
    public V get(K key){
        //...
    }

    public void set(K key, V v){
        //...
    }
 }
```

Then, I create two subclasses:

```
class SuperMap<K,V> extends Map<K,V>{ /* ... */ }
class HyperMap<K,V> extends Map<K,V>{ /* ... */ }
```

What I want is to create a function that can take any map and print the string representation of each key and value. So I could just:

```
SuperMap<Unicorn, Horse> unicornsMap = ....;
HyperMap<Pegasus, Horse> pegasusMap = ....;

printMap(unicornsMap);
printMap(pegasusMap);
```

So, what should be the `printMap` function signature?

I tried with: `void printMap(Map<Object, Horse>)` But it doesn't work:

> The method `printMap(Map<Object,Horse>)` in the type MainClass is not
>   applicable for the arguments (`HyperMap<Pegasus,Horse>`)
>
> The method `printMap(Map<Object,String>)` in the type MainClass is not
>   applicable for the arguments (`SuperMap<Unicorn,Horse>`)

Comment: Do you want to create a function that takes *any* map (including `HashMap`, `TreeMap` and `Map` itself) or one that takes only a `HyperMap` and `SuperMap` ?

Comment: I don't think that `void printMap(SuperMap<Object, Horse>)` works with the first one. Could you check and edit ?

Comment: @Pache, you're right. I don't remember what intermediate solution I tried that seemed to work for one but not the other. Edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
printMap(Map<?, Horse>)
```

or, alternately

```
<K> printMap(Map<K, Horse>)
```

Comment: Because Generics in Java are not covariant.

Comment: Great. That works.

Is there a reason for that weird '?' syntax? why doesn't it support just simple inheritance? - EDIT: just saw @paht0m answer. Thanks, I have no idea what that means but I'll look into it.

Comment: If it was a `Map<Object, Horse>`, then you could do `map.put("foo", Horse)`.  But you can't do that with a `Map<Pegasus, Horse>`, because a `String` is not a `Pegasus`.  In other words, `Map<Object, Horse>` supports operations that `Map<Pegasus, Horse>` fundamentally cannot support, so it would be wrong to let you cast a `Map<Pegasus, Horse>` to a `Map<Object, Horse>`.

Comment: Basically, anything you put inside the `<>` brackets in a generic type definition must match EXACTLY.  In other words, the compiler sees `List<Object>` and `List<Integer>` as two different types (for the reasons listed by @LouisWasserman).

Comment: @JuanEnriqueMuñozZolotoochin Sorry, if Java was covariant, that would mean that a type X<B> would be considered a subtype of X<A>, is B is a subtype of A. (In your example: A is Object, B is Unicorn). See Louis' explanation for why that doesn't work out that well. Arrays in Java *are* covariant, which may leads to runtime exceptions. What does work is this however: B<X> is considered a subtype of A<X>, if B is a subtype of A. Using `?` will create a custom method for each type.